# Want to return all matches with regex alternation

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I want to use a regex in vb.net with several character sequences separated by the alternation character `|`. The patterns will be built by a program for finding confidential number sequences and identifying text. I want to find all matches of any of the identifying text patterns in my input. For example with this pattern:

```
\b(?i)(social security|credit card number|social security number|SSN)\b
```

And this input text:

> Social security examples Social Security Number 426-54-3468. (SSN:426-76-2456) My SSN Is: 087-38-4646. SOCIAL SECURITY NUMBER 087 40 6482. credit card number 1222 2333 3444 4555 My SSN is:087-40-5434

Three matches are found for `"social security"`, one for `"credit card number"`, and two for `"SSN"`. Are there any quantifiers that I can add to match `"Social Security Number"` and `"SOCIAL SECURITY NUMBER"` also, or is the only way to code `"social security number"` before `"social security"`? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `social security` string is a substring of `social security number` and the former goes first in the alternation. If you'd had `... |social security number|social security| ...` then the longer would match first giving you the desired output. I doubt there are any easier ways to achieve the same with other regex features (well, you might have tried something like `social security(?!= number)` but this is rather hard to implement for arbitrary strings.)

As a rule of thumb, when dynamically building alternation patterns from arbitrary strings, sort these strings in their length descending order.

Another handy rule is to quote any regex special characters potentially found in the strings you're building pattern from. This can be done with `Regex.Escape()`.

So the pattern composing code may look as follows:

```
Dim pattern = "\b(?i)(" _
    + String.Join("|",
        confidentialStrings _
            .OrderByDescending(Function(s) s.Length) _
            .[Select](Function(s) Regex.Escape(s))) _
    + ")\b"
```

VB.Net demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nOWrMb